# Change square matrix in diagonal without numpy - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I have some data:

```
values = [2.1254,0.0125,1.3542,0.2543]
residuals = [0.0251,0.0005,0.1223,0.0043]
```

then I created a matrix:

```
matrix = [[i] * len(values) for i in values]
```

and now I would like to add up the residuals vector to diagonal in matrix.
I tried:

```
def fc(x)
    for i in range(len(values)):
        x[i][i] + residuals[i]
```

but I do not know how to return a result.

```
print(fc(matrix))
```

returns `None`

This is desired matrix:

```
matrix1 = [[2.1505,2.1254,2.1254,2.1254],
[0.0125,0.013,0.0125,0.0125,
[1.3542,1.3542,1.4765,1.3542]
[0.2543,0.2543,0.2543,0.2586]]
```

Comment: First of all matrix is a vector of length 4: [4,8,12,16], so there is no way you can access the position [i][i]. Second, you are missing a colon after function definition, also missing indentation and variable definition... Third, code is wrong at so many levels, you should do a programming and Python tutorial friend!

Comment: @LauroBravar "matrix" is not a vector, it is a square matrix, which have same numbers in rows. I know there are elementary mistakes in definition of function and I am trying to find them and understand them.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'd like to help, but I'm not familiar with residuals vector. Is there a reference on how the mathematics works?

Comment: @davedwards I am not sure that I understand. I just want to sum up the diagonal with the vector, there is no mathematical operation for that.

Comment: @AdamSrut, ok thanks for explanation. So in that case, should `sum([float(i), residuals[i]])` work?

Comment: @davedwards still returns none, I should somehow force the function to return the matrix with changed diagonal.

Comment: @AdamSrut sounds reasonable. what should the answer be? can you provide correct outputs for that (or any corresponding) example input?

Comment: @davedwards I edited question and added wanted output.

Comment: thank you @AdamSrut, check if answer below works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using a list comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
values = [2.1254,0.0125,1.3542,0.2543]
residuals = [0.0251,0.0005,0.1223,0.0043]

def fc(values, residuals):
    n = len(values)
    res = [[i]*n for i in values]
    for idx, j in enumerate(residuals):
        res[idx][idx] += j
    return res

res = fc(values, residuals)
```

Result:

```
[[2.1505, 2.1254, 2.1254, 2.1254],
 [0.0125, 0.013, 0.0125, 0.0125],
 [1.3542, 1.3542, 1.4765, 1.3542],
 [0.2543, 0.2543, 0.2543, 0.2586]]
```